# What does "let's shoot the shit" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics, register

English lyrics by Halestorm rock band:

**Here's to us**:

```
Get another bottle out 
Lets shoot the shit //What does it mean?
Sit back down 
For just one more drink, 
oh yeah
```

In some sites it's translated from English like "`Let's chat`". Is it correctly? If yes, answer me please, how is chatter related with shooting to excrement from the point of view of English-speaking people?

Comment: The language of army privates, who are sitting in mud and eating cold food from a can and worrying about getting killed, or the language of stevedores unloading ships in all kinds of weather (just to cite two examples) will often express simple facts in rather unpleasant ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it's a variation on "**to shoot the breeze**", which means "**to chat casually**"

[Shoot the shit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shoot_the_shit#English)